# How to set QListView Opacity ,setWindowOpacity doesn't work

Tags: qt, transparency, qlistview

I'm trying to set opacity to QListView , that sits on QDialog
I manage to set the QDialog transperant with setting the :Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground = true
but the QList doesn't become transparent with i set the setWindowOpacity to 1 or 0

Comment: you want to set the opacity to listview item background?

Comment: i like to set opacity to all the QlistView Widget